# Rancher import cluster Error: Error while applying agent YAML, it will be retried automatically

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, rancher

- Rancher version: v2.6.8
- AWS EKS cluster version: 1.2.1

I created another Rancher and I accidentally executed the yaml provided by this Rancher on cluster A. I delete cluster A in Rancher and try to reimport it. Now it's not working properly.

```
[Error] Error while applying agent YAML, it will be retried automatically: exit status 1, Error from server (InternalError): an error on the server ("unable to create impersonator account: error setting up impersonation for user u-qjbo6ceucp: impersonation: error creating secret for service account cattle-impersonation-u-qjbo6ceucp") has prevented the request from succeeding
```

[image]

I deleted the cluster in Rancher, tried importing in new Rancher, got the same error.